# Denture Tablet Problem

Tags: general-topology

So, I recently noticed something interesting while I was using denture tablets to clean my invisalign retainers.

The denture tablets I buy usually come in 2x3 tablet tear-open packaging. I like to pre-tear one of these 2x3 tablet "pages" so that they fit more nicely on my sink. I became curious as to what would be the smallest number of tears required to get all 6 tablets seperated from one another.

When I gave it some thought, I realized that the number of tears seems to always be 5.

If I tear down the longer axis into 3x1 strips, I have to do 2 more tears for each of these strips for a total of 5.

Also, if I tear a page into a 1x2 strip and a 2x2 strip, I need to do 1 tear for the 1x2 and 3 for the 2x2.

I think this holds true for other numbers of tablets as well. The general rule is a page with n tablets requires n-1 tears.

I also experimented with other shapes other than rectangular, and it seems that the only thing that changes this characteristic number of tears is how many "holes" the page has. All pages of any shape with n tablets require n-1 tears, so long as the page has no holes.

E.g.

```
XXXXXX
XX
```

and

```
XXXX
XXXX
```

require 7 tears no matter how you tear either of them, but:

```
XXX
XOX
XXX
```

requires 8 tears no matter what.

I have a passing familiarity with topology, but never studied it formally (although i do have a b.s. in mathematics). I was wondering if anyone could confirm I'm correct or show a counterexample. I feel like this is probably well-traveled ground for people who specialize in topology, but I wasn't sure what exactly this problem might be called. I feel like it might have something to do with Euler characteristics but idk.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you don't have holes, each tear increases the number of pieces by at most $1$. You start with $1$ piece and end up with $n$, so need to tear at least $n - 1$ times. I don't see how the case with a hole requires $8$ tears, depending on what tears are allowed I get $6$ or $7$?

Comment: @ronno so basically, i considered a tear to be a tear in a single direction (up-down or left-right), also there must always be a table on each side of the tear, so you cant have a tear have nothing on one side and something on the other. I'm not sure if that explains it succinctly but that's the general idea. Also i didn't consider that every year in pages with no holes would just increase the number of pieces by one, so for no holes it is always n-1. Pretty obvious now that you've mentioned it haha

Comment: Okay, depending on other implicit rules, one of these should separate the "ring" in $7$ tears: either, separate the first column with one tear and then take off tablets one-by-one for six more tears, or separate the two columns with two tears and then take off one tablet each for five more tears, one for the central column and two each for the others.